# Converting const struct reference to non-const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, reference

I am trying to work out how to convert a const struct reference to a non-const struct pointer.

I have a struct called Foo:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo& someFunc()
    {
        //do something

        return *this;
    }
};
```

I have a method:

```
struct Bar
{
    Foo* fooPointer;

    void anotherFunc(const Foo& foo)
    {
        // set fooPointer to foo's pointer
    }
};
```

I will call it like this:

```
Foo foo;
Bar bar;
bar.anotherFunc(foo.someFunc());
```

But how do I write anotherFunc()?

```
void anotherFunc(const Foo& foo)
{
    fooPointer = &foo;  // <-- This doesn't work as foo is still const
}
```

Comment: Why does `anotherFunc` need to take a const reference?

Comment: If you need to store a pointer to a non-const object pass a non-const reference, otherwise you're just begging for trouble.

Comment: @ecatmur For the sake of the example, it simply does. I am asking a very specific question, not looking for assistance restructuring my code.

Comment: When the code does something silly the right thing to do is question whether it really needs to do that.

Comment: I appreciate that. My comment may be taken the wrong way. I meant it in a matter of fact way ...not in a complaining way. I try and write questions in a very concise manner as it get's a better response from you guys... but that usually means I receive the same few initial questions each time :-/

Comment: If you're usually receiving the same few initial questions, perhaps you should anticipate them and include the relevant information.

Comment: I thought "I am trying to work out how to convert a const struct reference to a non-const struct pointer" pretty much nailed what I was asking. The rest ...fluff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accept it directly as a pointer or non-const reference to `Foo`.

The way you're passing your `Foo`, you won't be able to do that without a `const_cast`, which feels wrong except in a few precise case.

As you're storing it with a pointer to non-const `Foo`, you should take the parameter as non-const also. Think about the interface: your struct has a function that takes a `Foo` with const qualification, implying "I will only peak at it", but then your function casts it and stores it in a way that allows modification. It's a bit like lying to users of your code (and you are the first user of your code).

Answer (score 6):

The best answer is "don't do that, it's crazy". Either change the pointer type to `const Foo*` if it won't be used to modify the object, or the reference to `Foo&` if it will.

If you genuinely have a good reason to discard const-correctness, then there's a cast for that

```
fooPointer = const_cast<Foo*>(&foo);
```

but first consider why you want to do this, and how you can prevent the error of ending up with a non-const pointer to a const object. Or worse, a pointer to a temporary that lingers after its demise.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your input is appreciated... as always.

Comment: @Beanie: bear in mind anotherFunc may be called with a temporary value. Retaining a pointer to a temporary is a disaster waiting to happen.